# add link to jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a href link to jquery append. The link opens an ajax modal when clicked.

here's what I have

```
  $('<div/>').text(message.text).prepend($('<em/>')
  .text('Opponent: '+ opponentName + ',' + ' ' + 'Game amount: ' + message.amount + ' ' + 'tokens,' + ' ' + 'Game: ' + message.game + ' ' + '<a href="#" data-toggle="ajaxModal">accept</a>')).appendTo($('#pendingChallenges'));
        $('#pendingChallenges')[0].scrollTop =    $('    #pendingChallenges')[0].scrollHeight;
```

Comment: To clarify you want your structure to look like this: `<div><em>message.text</em>Opponent: opponentName, Game amount: amount tokens, Game: game<a>accept</a>`?

Comment: @user1034372 Don't forget the closing `</div>`. :)

Comment: True! Also, I don't know what the `#pendingChallenges` is an id for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `text` to have your html string to be represented as html instead of textcontent which is what happens when you use text.

```
$('<div/>').text(message.text).prepend($('<em/>')
   .html(...
```